# Assistance with sed command file please

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I created the following bash pipeline that will take the output of "who" and modify it to meet an assignment's requirements

This is the pipline:

```
who | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g" | sed 's/[.]/ /g' | sed 's/ Pts\// TTY /g' | sed '1d' | sed -n 's/     .*$/ /gp'
```

After putting this into a sed file that looks like this:

```
s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g
s/[.]/ /g
s/ Pts\// TTY /g
1d
s/     .*$/ /gp
```

And then running it like such:

```
who | sed -f sedfile
```

The output is correct in that everything is in the format of:

```
firstName lastName TTY (a number)
```

However each line is printed twice, where the pipeline properly printed each line once

Would anyone happen to know the issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the gp at the last line. You're not running with sed -n (no-print), so by default you're running with sed -yesprint (or whatever). Then you hit that gp, which prints, and you get two copies.

Convert to `sed -n`, or change the `gp` to just `g`. Or better still, get rid of it, since the match pattern contains $, so it will only ever run in one place - the end of the line.